# php simplexml foreach and while loop

Tags: php

I am using php simplexml and foreach to loop a xml file.
the code just like

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file(myfile.xml);
foreach($xml->contents as $list){
     $name= $list->name;
         $price=$list->price;
         $prob=$list->Price;

    echo $name, $price, $prob;
}
```

If I have 100 items, how can I insert a class for every 5 items?

the output like

```
<div id="showup"> 
$name, $price, $prob (1)
$name, $price, $prob (2)
$name, $price, $prob (3)
$name, $price, $prob (4)
$name, $price, $prob (5)
</div>
<div id="showup"> 
$name, $price, $prob (6)
$name, $price, $prob (7)
$name, $price, $prob (8)
$name, $price, $prob (9)
$name, $price, $prob (10)
</div>
...............
```

Do I have to use while instead of foreach? the advantage for foreach is that, I dont need to count how many items in the xml file. or I can use both

hope someone could help, thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
<div id="showup">
<?php foreach($xml->contents as $list) {

    $name= $list->name;
    $price=$list->price;
    $prob=$list->Price;

   echo $name, $price, $prob;
   $counter++;
   if( $counter % 5 == 0) { 
?>
</div><div id='showup'> 
<?php } } ?>
```